# How to configure Cron timezone in a Spring config.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, cron

I have a Spring configuration xml file with a Cron task. The task gets executed periodically on my machine. 
How can I configure this task in the xml file to use Moscow timezone (that is different from mine)?

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="productTask" method="loadProduct" cron="0 0 10 * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

**Edit:** I have double checked the syntax and changed the code a little bit. But it still doesn't work for me. 
Below I've provided the last configuration I came up with. Here I'm getting the following exception: `Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "moscowTimeCronSchedule")`

So task "scheduler" requires cron expression instead of `cron="moscowTimeCronSchedule"`. I need to figure out how is it possible to pass a bean reference to it instead of the pure cron expression.

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1"/>

    <bean id="moscowTimeZone" class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Europe/Moscow"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="moscowTimeCronSchedule" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger"
          c:expression="*/15 * * * * *"
          c:timeZone-ref="moscowTimeZone"/>

    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="productTask" method="loadProduct" cron="moscowTimeCronSchedule"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

*I found this link helpful but it didn't answer the question: how to pass a bean instead of a cron expression.*
http://websystique.com/spring/spring-job-scheduling-using-xml-configuration/

Comment: What you have there is "execute every half-hour". This cron does not benefit from a time zone, unless your machine somehow is in a zone offset like `3:15` or something.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Wow.. sorry. The actual config has `cron="0 0 10 * * *"` Will edit post to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Spring configures a CronTask, it uses a simple constructor form which accepts `String`. What you require is for it to use the second constructor, which accepts a `CronTrigger`. This should work (although, admittedly, I haven't tested it):

```
<bean
  id="moscowTimeZone"
  class="java.util.TimeZone"
  factory-method="getTimeZone">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Europe/Moscow"/>
</bean>

<bean
  id="moscowTimeCronSchedule"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="0 0 10 * * *"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.TimeZone" ref="moscowTimeZone"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="productTask" method="loadProduct" trigger="moscowTimeCronSchedule"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

What I did here:

1. Constructed a reference to moscow time zone and saved it as a bean in spring configuration.
2. Constructed a Cron Trigger instance as another bean using that time zone and a cron expression
3. Used the Cron Trigger in scheduled task constructor.

Admittedly, this solution is a bit long-winded, but it sounds like it should do its job.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Element 'constructor-arg' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.` Something is wrong with `<constructor-arg>Europe/Moscow</constructor-arg>`

Comment: Try with `<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Europe/Moscow"/>`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Error creating bean with name 'moscowTimeCronSchedule'. Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [java.util.TimeZone] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?`

Comment: @samba, I've just copied XML from my answer to my local Spring app config, and "moscowTimeCronSchedule" trigger bean gets created and autowired without any problems (except I'm autowiring it in my `@Service`, but it shouldn't matter given your error). Check that you have typed it right in yours.

Comment: I've double-checked that everything was typed right. It still doesn't work. Just added an edit to my post. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @samba, try using `trigger="..."` instead of `cron="..."` in task definition. This was my bad, I didn't check whether actual task configuration was fine, I just assumed it was. I've edited my answer with this as well.

Comment: I got this working by changing `java.lang.TimeZone` to `java.util.TimeZone`. I don't think `java.lang.TimeZone` is a thing