# spring instantiating java OffsetDateTime as a regular bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a test application that currenly running spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and using  the java 8 `OffsetDateTime` class. In one of my test classes I have a constructor that is taking `OffsetDateTime` as an argument. Spring is basically telling me I do not know have any knowledge of such bean. I do understand that error, however I would like to ask if there is a way to Spring to understand that this is a normal artifact that needs to be used i.e. i can not marked it as `@Component` / `@Service` / `@Repository` since that is jre code. 
I have  tried placing the jackson-datatype-jsr310 but as far as i understand this only helps for serialization i.e. this is not telling spring , look you need to register `OffsetDateTime` as a component.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there a solution to this problem i.e. how can i use `OffsetDateTime` as a primitive i.e. (Integer, short, long etc.)

```
Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in org.bl67.xl.TestingDates required a bean of type 'java.time.OffsetDateTime' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.time.OffsetDateTime' in your configuration.
```

here is the related class

```
@Component
public class TestingDates implements TestingDatesInterface {


        public TestingDates(
                RoomsInterface rooms, 
                IdInterface id, 
                TelefonInterface telefon,
                OffsetDateTime lastOffsetDateTime
                ){
    ...

    }
```

and i am calling it using the applicationContext such as

```
applicationContext.getBean(TestingDatesInterface.class, rooms, id, telefon, lastDate);
```

Comment: Please also share relevant configuration which uses that value. You might be able to define `<constuctor-arg>`, similarly to how I've outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473036/7470253) answer. If change is required, you could define it a prototype bean with `factory-method` `now`.

Comment: Even assuming Spring can create and inject an OffsetDateTime, which value should it inject? How could your code make any sense if it takes any OffsetDateTime as argument? My guess is that you have a design problem, and the constructor shouldn't have an OffsetDatetime as argument. if you really need a bean of type OffsetDateTime, then just define it: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  Privet g-n Prokhorov, unfortunately i have never used xml so far, can you please advice how will that look with java. I mean my class already have a constructor, and the type of the arguments is also know. I am not following the logic here, can you please elaborate. As far as i understand i need to make the offsetdatetime a compoment for spring so it can register as a bean. How is <constructor-args> usefull in this case. Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: JBNizet thank you for your responce, I am using OffsetDateTime only to transport particular instance of time, you mentioned that i can define it you what od you mean by  that ? should i have class that extends offsetdate time and mark that as with the @Component annotation. Can you please give a simple example?

Comment: I gave you a link pointing to the specific section of the documentation explaining how to define beans. Click it, and read.