# Delay in scheduled task execution in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

we have Spring scheduler executing multiple task which is configured in a xml file. all tasks run 1 hour late possibly because of daylight-saving. I couldn't add zone to xml file. does anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471853/how-to-configure-cron-timezone-in-a-spring-config-xml ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.